# Switching between fullscreen and windowed in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, opengl, sdl, fullscreen

I have a project in the works with OpenGL and SDL. Users have the option of using a full-screen or windowed mode for the display.

I use `SDL_SetVideoMode` to set up the window, but this solution destroys the original `SDL_Surface` context (so all my OpenGL textures get cleaned too).

How can I correctly switch between full-screen and windowed mode without textures cleaning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reload all your textures unfortunately. This is neccesary because SDL recreates the context. It's an SDL issue that is planned to be fixed someday.

More info [here](http://www.gamedev.net/community/forums/topic.asp?topic_id=557497&whichpage=1&#3579962).

Comment: Ah, that's one of about 10 problems I'm having explained :) Thanks.